# Problems with my lens

Tags: lens, maintenance

Hi i have had a Nikon 200mm lens for about three years now. I did not use it for about six months and when i used it again it was all fuzzy. I have tried everything.

Is it because it is so old?

I have also read that it might be a piece that is loose inside. What should I do? Should I pay to have it fixed or should I just get a new lens?

Comment: Can you post a sample image?  This is basically impossible to judge otherwise.  An image looking down the lens from the front would also be helpful if possible.  Also, I assume you mean a Nikon/Nikor lens, not a Nike lens.  Nike makes sneakers, not lenses (well, maybe sunglass lenses).

Comment: Also, are there any visible problems with the glass? Smears, spiderweb-like fungus, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Three years is not old for a lens. Is it possible that it was very cold and accumulated humidity from a warmer environment when you were using it? In that case, just let it rest to get the same temperature, and the humidity will disappear.